# Lucene autocomplete implement suggest.InputIterator to include multiple filed

Tags: java, indexing, autocomplete, lucene, full-text-search

I am implementing an autocomplete using lucene **AnalyzingSuggerter** API.

I have a data class as below

```
class Student implements java.io.Serializable {
    int id;
    String fullName;
    String description;


    public Student(int id, String fullName, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
}
```

I have implemented the iterator as follows

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.InputIterator;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;


class CourseIterator implements InputIterator
{
    private Iterator<Course> courseIterator;
    private Course currentCourse;

    CourseIterator(Iterator<Course> courseIterator) {
        this.courseIterator = courseIterator;
    }

    public boolean hasContexts() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean hasPayloads() {
        return true;
    }

    public Comparator<BytesRef> getComparator() {
        return null;
    }

    public BytesRef next() {
        if (courseIterator.hasNext()) {
            currentCourse = courseIterator.next();
            try {
                return new BytesRef(currentCourse.fullName.getBytes("UTF8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                throw new Error("Couldn't convert to UTF-8");
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }


    // payload is a serialized Java object representing our course.
    public BytesRef payload() {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject(currentCourse);
            out.close();
            return new BytesRef(bos.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Well that's unfortunate.");
        }
    }

    public Set<BytesRef> contexts() {
        throw new Error("Unsupported Operation");
    }

    public long weight() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

This works fine for data

```
new Student(1, "Elizabeth Smith", "test1");
new Student(2, "Will Smith", "test2");
new Student(3, "Smith Brown", "test3");
new Student(4, "Queen Elizabeth", "test4");
new Student(5, "Elena sam", "test1");

on auto suggestion search for

Eliz --> [1]
Smit --> [3]
El   --> [1, 5]
Que  --> [4]
```

I also wanted to taken the last name part of the fullname into account for autosearch therefore the result should be were lastname was taken into account and has less weight.

```
Eliz --> [1, 4]
Smit --> [3, 2]
El   --> [1, 5, 4]
Que  --> [4]
```

Can anyone suggest how to achive this?